# Enum with another enum as keys

Tags: python, enums

Im working on a project where adapters never raise Exceptions. Instead, it returns a Result object like this:

```py
Dto = TypeVar("Dto", bound=BaseModel)


class BaseError(BaseModel):
    error_code: DomainErrorEnum
    message: str

    def raise_error(self):
        raise ErrorMap[self.error_code] # Here is the big deal


class Result(BaseModel, Generic[Dto]):
    error = Optional[BaseError]
    data: Optional[Dto]
```

Where `DomainErrorEnum` is an Enum that maps slugs that represent our DomainErrors.

What I like to do is a `ErrorMap` class that works like this:

```py
class ErrorMap(DomainErrorEnum, Enum):
    DomainErrorEnum.GENERIC_ERROR = GenericErrorException
    DomainErrorEnum.NOT_FOUND = CartNotFoundException
    DomainErrorEnum.OUT_OF_STOCK = OutOfStockException
```

Doing this, I have 2 things well segregated:

1. An Enum (actually we have many `"DomainErrorEnum"`, but Im pretending here that we have only one to make my example easy to understand) that has the responsability to represents (slugs) all my domain errors
2. A class that know which Exception it should throw whatever I want to trhow it (remember, my adapters never raise anything, it always return a `Result[SpecificDto]` object

Any idea on how to represent these 2 things?

Just for clarify:

```py
# On domain module:
def specific_use_case():
    result_search: Result[ProductDto] = adapter.search_product()
    if product_dto.is_success:
        data: ProductDto = result_search.data
        result_search.business_rules_method(data) # Here, on pure business rules we throw exceptions without using our map, because here we dont use these Result pattern
        return entity

    result_search.error.raise_error()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ErrorMap` should probably *be* a map (a dictionary):

```
ERROR_MAP = {
    DomainErrorEnum.GENERIC_ERROR: GenericErrorException,
    DomainErrorEnum.NOT_FOUND: CartNotFoundException,
    DomainErrorEnum.OUT_OF_STOCK: OutOfStockException
}
```

Comment: Oh should work, maybe im thinking too much about classes lol